# How to upload image in ckeditor reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor

Before I was using **react-ckeditor-component** package in this package image upload option of file is not available but upload image through link option is available. Now I tried **@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react** and **ckeditor5-build-full** these two packages , I am still not able to upload the photos and one more thing my ck-editor [editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uwUQ.png) toolbar disabled by these two packages.

Comment: We truly need a code sample of what exactly you are doing here!

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-feistel-0xw92?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The example that you provided does not work. The error that I found is that you should fix url in your config to this 

"url: ` ${BASE_URL}/common/Uploads?type=${CKEditorImages} `"